# Swapping partial derivatives and limits

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

What conditions does a function have to meet for the following to be true?

$$\displaystyle\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(x,y)=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\lim_{x\to 0}f(x,y)$$

I've looked both on MSE and tried googling this question as well but I can't find a good answer. Any explanation or resources you could point me to would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Does [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/409178/can-i-exchange-limit-and-differentiation-for-a-sequence-of-smooth-functions) give you what you need?

Comment: @StephenDonovan yes, I believe it does thank you!

Comment: There’s something seriously wrong. The expression on the right is always $0$, since the limit is a function of $y$ alone.